# Has anyone aware of CP210x_VCP_Win_XP_S2K3_Vista_7.exe

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I googled for CP210x_VCP_Win_XP_S2K3_Vista_7 but did not find much information other than release note. Please detailed me on same.

Good links also welcomed.

Comment: I don't think SO is a correct place to ask this. Try superuser instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a quick Google for [CP210x VCP](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=v61&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=CP210x+VCP&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) points you to http://www.silabs.com/products/interface/usbtouart/Pages/default.aspx which suggests that whatever you have is a driver for some kind of USB to serial converter, intended for connection of all sorts of legacy type devices that don't support USB on their own.

[This page](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/pages/usbtouartbridgevcpdrivers.aspx) has the drivers and looks like they exactly match the file name you are looking at.

http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/Software/CP210x_VCP_Win_XP_S2K3_Vista_7.exe

Comment: This package is now obsolete, but the driver can still be obtained here: http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/Software/CP210x_VCP_Windows.zip